# Stuck on Splash Screen Issue with Drawer.Navigator in React Native

Tags: android, react-native, expo, navigation-drawer

I'm new to React Native, and I'm facing an issue that I can't seem to resolve. My code works correctly in development mode, but when I compile it into a .apk file, it gets stuck on the splash screen.

After debugging and gradually compiling different parts of my code, I've determined that the error is coming from the Drawer.Navigator component.

While searching online, I found people who had a similar problem and solved it by using useLegacyImplementation={true}. However, in my case, I'm encountering the following error:
`Error: The` useLegacyImplementation`prop is not available with Reanimated 3 as it no longer includes support for Reanimated 1 legacy API. Remove the`useLegacyImplementation`prop from`Drawer.Navigator `to be able to use it.`

*Navegation.jsx*

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';
import React from 'react';
import Main from './Main';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function NavegationDrawerSuplemente() {

  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator 
    useLegacyImplementation={true}
    >
      <Drawer.Screen name="Portada" component={Main} 

    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}
export default NavegationDrawerSuplemente;
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.4.0",
    "@fortawesome/react-native-fontawesome": "^0.3.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.18.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.17",
    "expo": "^49.0.0",
    "expo-device": "~5.4.0",
    "expo-font": "~11.4.0",
    "expo-notifications": "~0.20.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.10.1",
    "react-native": "0.72.4",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "react-native-progress-steps": "^1.3.4",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.3.0",
    "react-native-render-html": "^6.3.4",
    "react-native-svg": "13.9.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

I attempted to Error Search with ADB and also tried downgrading the React Native Reanimated library to an older version

Comment: Hello,
You have made the mistake I have done in the past.
You told us the whole story but you did NOT pose a clear question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.